# JPA query.getResultList will only return 1 row of my datatable?

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa, datatable

I am using mvc+spring+primefaces and I have defined the following method in my DAO:

```
public Pet retrieveAllPet() {

    Query query = em.createQuery("from Pet");



    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<Pet> pets = query.getResultList();
    Pet pet = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < pets.size(); i++){
        pet = (Pet) pets.get(i);
    }

    return pet;
```

Now when I run my application it will only return the last row of my datatable?
Should the above return the full table or does my problem lie somewhere else?

Thank you very much.

Comment: what problem? you return the last entry of the List you were given. So was that on purpose?

Comment: Please state your problem correctly. What do you want to do?

Answer (score 2):

You are returning a single `Pet` instance in your method stored in the `pet` variable. This variable will store the last row when `i` reaches the `pets.size() - 1`.

To return all rows, simply change the return type to a `List<Pet>` and return the variable `pets`.

```
public List<Pet> retrieveAllPet() {

    Query query = em.createQuery("from Pet");

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<Pet> pets = query.getResultList();
    return pets;
}
```